# Matlab graphing: aligning convolution to a vector

Tags: matlab, graphing

I'm trying to graph a convolution based on a vector.

Here's what I have so far:

```
>> n=[-10:10];
>> x=zeros(1,length(n));
>> x(n==-1)=1;
>> x(n==0)=1;
>> x(n==1)=-1;
>> u=zeros(1,length(n));
>> u(n>=0)=1;
>> h=(1/2).^n .* u;
>> y = conv(x,h)
```

Now I want to graph y using `stem(n,y)` or something like that but `y` wouldn't be aligned to `n` anymore as they are different lengths already.

Is there a way to align my old vector `n` to my new equation `y` when I'm graphing them? Or at least align my y-values to the right x-axis values.

Comment: use `conv(x,h,'same')`

Comment: perfect! you should post down there so I can pick it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
y= conv(x,h,'same')
```

This returns the central part of the convolution of the same size as `x`.